# angular 5 test static method of component

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have a static method on my Component class that I am testing, my question is how it is possible to access that method within my spec testing file?

So far I can access a component instance with:

```
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
```

Comment: Please, provide all relevant data. What is this static method? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Static methods are not bound to instances of classes. So something like this should work: `MyComponent.nameOfStaticMethod(params)`

Comment: Sweet! Good luck!